# Widget Vs Properties' Values in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart

I am an absolute beginner in FLUTTER and the thing which is confusing me is that when to pass a **widget** in a ***property*** and when to pass a **property value(someclass.something / some value)** in a *property*

```
void main() => runApp(
MaterialApp(
  title: "APPLICATION ON TESTING",
  home: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('This is APP BAR'),),
  body:   Material(
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
       "HELLO WORLD",
       textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellowAccent, fontSize: 30.0),
       ),
      ),
    ),
   ) 
 )
);
```

> In the provided code ***textDirection:*** is a **property** in which ***TextDirection.ltr*** is passed. While in ***style*** **property** we have passed a **widget** called ***TextStyle()***
>
> **Is there any rule of thumb regarding this, which can help me in flutter development?**

Comment: there is no rule of thumb. In case you are unsure what to fill in, just hit CMD+B in Android Studio when cursor is on the property. This will jump to the sources and you will see the Type or the thing which should be put in there,

Comment: any **vs code alternative** for this command

Comment: i think its Ctrl+F12.